# Angular Material Theme Compiling

Tags: angular, angular-material, theming

I made my theme.scss file and put it in src where it is supposed to be and then added it to the angular-cli.json file, but then what? Where is the css file that is supposed to be compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You should install [sass](http://sass-lang.com/install) in order to generate the final css files you're looking for. Once installed you can run:

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

and you can read more about it [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html).

Comment: But I don't want to install it. Angular says it will compile it on its own.